# Example of nonempty partially ordered set (S, R)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

When asked a question like this:

Give an example of a nonempty partially ordered set (S, R) that does not have incomparable elements. Draw the Hasse diagram for this partially ordered set

would this be a correct answer:

$S =$ {$1, 2, 4, 6$}

$R =${$(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 2), (4, 2),(2,6), (4, 4), (6, 6)$}

Comment: Apparently not. $4$ and $6$ appear to be incomparable.

Comment: @MattSamuel what if I just did S= {1,2,4,8}?

Comment: There's a bit of a deeper problem, notice that your relation is not even transitive, so it's not a partial ordering.

Comment: take any linear order, say $S=\{0,1\}$, $R=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$, or $S=\{0\}, R=\{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: "Partially ordered set that does not have incomparable elements" is just a long-winded way of saying "totally ordered set".

Comment: @Henning: Possibly. If they mean "partially ordered set in which no two elements are incomparable," then you're correct. If they mean "partially ordered set such that each element is comparable to at least one other element," then a total order still works, but there are other options.